# Generating Pandas Dataframes with a For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to generate 500 DataFrames, one for each student. Each DataFrame will be their attendance records.

**(Bonus)** How can I set the name of each DataFrame to be `attendance_i`. Where i is the ID of the student. So, the DataFrame for student 1 would be attendance_1, for student 2 it'd be attendance_2, etc.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.rrule import DAILY, rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU
import calendar

# DEFINE GLOBAL VARIABLES
student_count = 500

# DECLARE START AND END DATES
start = '2013-03-01'
end = '2015-07-31'
# GET NUMBER OF WORKDAYS
weekmask = 'Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'
customworkweek = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask=weekmask)
workdates = pd.bdate_range(start = start, end = end, freq = customworkweek).to_pydatetime().tolist()
# GET NUMBER OF WEEKS AND MONTHS 
x = pd.to_datetime(end) - pd.to_datetime(start)
workweeks_int = int(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'W'))
workmonths_int = int(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))
# MORE GLOBAL VARAIBLES
wed = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Wed')
thu = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Thu')
fri = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Fri')
sat = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Sat')
sun = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Sun')

wed_classes = pd.bdate_range(start = start, end = end, freq = wed).to_pydatetime().tolist()
thu_classes = pd.bdate_range(start = start, end = end, freq = thu).to_pydatetime().tolist()
fri_classes = pd.bdate_range(start = start, end = end, freq = fri).to_pydatetime().tolist()
sat_classes = pd.bdate_range(start = start, end = end, freq = sat).to_pydatetime().tolist()
sun_classes = pd.bdate_range(start = start, end = end, freq = sun).to_pydatetime().tolist()

# SET UP STUDENT DATAFRAME
student_age = random.randint(4, 13, size = (student_count))
student_sex = random.choice(["male", "female"], size = (student_count))
student_id = list(range(0,student_count))
student_name_local = pd.read_csv('Database\student_name_local.csv')
student_name_english = pd.read_csv('Database\student_name_english.csv')
class_id = random.randint(1, 27, size = (student_count))

column_names = ['STUDENT_ID', 'STUDENT_NAME_LOCAL', 'STUDENT_NAME_ENGLISH', 'STUDENT_AGE', 'STUDENT_SEX']
students = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

students['STUDENT_ID'] = student_id
students['STUDENT_NAME_LOCAL'] = student_name_local
students['STUDENT_NAME_ENGLISH'] = student_name_english
students['STUDENT_AGE'] = student_age
students['STUDENT_SEX'] = student_sex
students['CLASS_ID'] = class_id

# SET UP CLASSES DATAFRAME
data = [['0', 'Wednesday', '16:30:00'], ['1', 'Wednesday', '17:30:00'], ['2', 'Wednesday', '18:30:00'], ['3', 'Thursday', '16:30:00'], ['4', 'Thursday', '17:30:00'], ['5', 'Thursday', '18:30:00'], ['6', 'Friday', '16:30:00'], ['7', 'Friday', '17:30:00'], ['8', 'Friday', '18:30:00'], ['9', 'Saturday', '8:30:00'], ['10', 'Saturday', '9:30:00'], ['11', 'Saturday', '10:30:00'], ['12', 'Saturday', '11:30:00'], ['13', 'Saturday', '13:30:00'], ['14', 'Saturday', '14:30:00'], ['15', 'Saturday', '15:30:00'], ['16', 'Saturday', '16:30:00'], ['17', 'Saturday', '17:30:00'], ['18', 'Sunday', '8:30:00'], ['19', 'Sunday', '9:30:00'], ['20', 'Sunday', '10:30:00'], ['21', 'Sunday', '11:30:00'], ['22', 'Sunday', '13:30:00'], ['23', 'Sunday', '14:30:00'], ['24', 'Sunday', '15:30:00'], ['25', 'Sunday', '16:30:00'], ['26', 'Sunday', '17:30:00']]

column_names = ['CLASS_ID', 'CLASS_DAY', 'CLASS_TIME']
classes = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = column_names)
classes['CLASS_ID'] = classes['CLASS_ID'].astype(int)

# FOR LOOP VARIABLES
attendance_status = random.choice(["present", "absent"], p = [0.95, 0.05], size = workweeks_int)

# THE FOR LOOP
for i in student_id:
    ids = list([i])*workweeks_int
    column_names = ['STUDENT_ID', 'CLASS_DATE', 'ATTENDANCE_STATUS']
    i = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

    i['STUDENT_ID'] = ids
    i['ATTENDANCE_STATUS'] = attendance_status

    x = students['CLASS_ID'].loc[students['STUDENT_ID'] == i].to_list()
    x = x[-1]
    c = classes['CLASS_DAY'].loc[classes['CLASS_ID'] == x].to_list()
    c = c[-1]

    if c == 'Wednesday':
        i['CLASS_DATE'] = wed_classes
    elif c == 'Thursday':
        i['CLASS_DATE'] = thu_classes
    elif c == 'Friday':
        i['CLASS_DATE'] = fri_classes
    elif c == 'Saturday':
        i['CLASS_DATE'] = sat_classes
    elif c == 'Sunday':
        i['CLASS_DATE'] = sun_classes
```

And here's the error that occurs during the for loop:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c04451cf4f9b> in <module>
     69     i['ATTENDANCE_STATUS'] = attendance_status
     70 
---> 71     x = students['CLASS_ID'].loc[students['STUDENT_ID'] == i].to_list()
     72     x = x[-1]
     73     c = classes['CLASS_DAY'].loc[classes['CLASS_ID'] == x].to_list()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1766 
   1767             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1768             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1769 
   1770     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1950 
   1951                 if hasattr(key, "ndim") and key.ndim > 1:
-> 1952                     raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
   1953 
   1954                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)

ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Interestingly enough, the following code works outside of a for loop:

```
attendance_status = random.choice(["present", "absent"], p = [0.95, 0.05], size = workweeks_int)
id = 326
i = list([id])*workweeks_int

column_names = ['STUDENT_ID', 'CLASS_DATE', 'ATTENDANCE_STATUS']
att1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

att1['STUDENT_ID'] = i
att1['ATTENDANCE_STATUS'] = attendance_status

x = students['CLASS_ID'].loc[students['STUDENT_ID'] == id].to_list()
x = x[-1]
c = classes['CLASS_DAY'].loc[classes['CLASS_ID'] == x].to_list()
c = c[-1]

if c == 'Wednesday':
    att1['CLASS_DATE'] = wed_classes
elif c == 'Thursday':
    att1['CLASS_DATE'] = thu_classes
elif c == 'Friday':
    att1['CLASS_DATE'] = fri_classes
elif c == 'Saturday':
    att1['CLASS_DATE'] = sat_classes
elif c == 'Sunday':
    att1['CLASS_DATE'] = sun_classes

att1
```

Comment: are you able to edit the post so that others can run the code please, `NameError: name 'start' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I just made an edit that should do it.

Comment: NameError: name 'students' is not defined

Comment: (try clearing your memory and re-running)

Comment: Okay. I made another edit with everything, I think

Comment: sorry - i really encourage you to wipe your current session (restart notebook / whatever), and run this from scratch

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Can you include all the relevant code in a single block? Also, what do you mean by _How can I set the name of each DataFrame to be `Attendance_i`._ ?

Comment: Okay. I think I finally fixed it. Sorry it wasn't up to standards before.